# Overflow when computing binomial distribution for large n

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, computational-statistics, approximation

How do you compute a binomial probability distribution for large $n$? If I try the following, I get an integer overflow in any programming language:

```
n!/((n-k)! * k!) p^k * (1-p)^(n-k)
```

The problem is those factorials. Is there a way to deal with this? An approximation that works well for large $n$? I read that the binomial distribution can be approximated by a normal distribution for large $n$. That works, but not great, especially when $p \ne 0.5$. Maybe it works great for really large $n$. How else is this implemented?

Comment: This question seems to be more of a computational/programming type question than a statistical question. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096573/counting-combinations-and-permutations-efficiently) on stackoverflow might help.

Comment: Using logarithms is the primary recommendation in such settings, as e.g. `dbinom(x=1e3,s=1e6,p=1e-6,log=TRUE)` returning `[1] -5913.627` or even `dbinom(x=1e5,s=1e9,p=1e-9,log=TRUE)` producing `[1] -821055.7`

Comment: In addition to Xi'an suggestion, check also [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and [Poisson approximation] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).